# underscore__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__ is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, underscore.js, angular14upgrade

I am stuck with issue. Has anyone encountered this. As I am unable to get it what it is asking for.

This is how I imported this library highlighted in yellow.

[image]

[image]

This how it is showing in browser error.

[image]

Comment: If you scroll down on their page (https://underscorejs.org) to the section about "Monolithic import", you'll find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```js
import * as _ from 'underscore';
```

you need to

```js
import _ from 'underscore';
```